# C++: Convert wchar_t* to BSTR?

Tags: c++, string, com, bstr

I'm trying to convert a `wchar_t *` to `BSTR`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t* pwsz = L"foo"; 

    BSTR bstr(pwsz);

    cout << SysStringLen(bstr) << endl;

    getchar();
}
```

This prints `0`, which is less than what I'd hoped. What is the correct way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use SysAllocString (and then SysFreeString).

```
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(pwsz);

// ...

SysFreeString(bstr);
```

A `BSTR` is a managed string with the characters of the string prefixed by their length. `SysAllocString` allocates the correct amount of storage and set up the length and contents of the string correctly. With the `BSTR` correctly initialized, `SysStringLen` should return the correct length.

If you're using C++ you might want to consider using a RAII style class (or even Microsoft's `_bstr_t`) to ensure that you don't forget any `SysFreeString` calls.

Answer (score 2):

`SysStringLen()` should only be used on BSTRs allocated by `SysAllocString()` family functions. Using it as you do will lead to undefined behavior - program can crash or produce unexpected results. Better yet use wrapper classes - `ATL::CComBSTR` or `_bstr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest is either to use

[CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288%28VS.80%29.aspx)

or

[CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f%28VS.80%29.aspx)

both have methods that do what Charles mentioned

Comment: `CString` doesn't _wrap_ a `BSTR`, although it has a method to allocate a `BSTR` from a `CString` ( `.AllocSysString()` ). `CString` doesn't help with automatic freeing of a `BSTR`, though.

Comment: well in a sense it wraps the functionality to convert to a BSTR which was what the OP wanted, but technically you are correct so my choice of words was not right.